# I can't get the id of button from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to get my button id from PHP file that were fetched and use it in javascript.

This is my javascript code

```
$("#heys").click(function(){
   var fruitCount = $(this).attr('data-fruit');
   console.log(fruitCount);
});
```

This button is from My PHP code

```
<td class="p-5 w-1/4 flex">
    <button  type="button" class=" text-white bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:border-gray-700"><a href="approve?approvid='.$id.'">Approve</a></button>
    <button  type="button" id="heys" data-fruit="<?php echo $id ?>" class="heys text-white bg-gray-800 hover:bg-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:hover:bg-gray-700 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:border-gray-700">DECLINE</button>
</td>
```

Please Help. Thanks

Comment: Do you see any errors?  Can you see in the DOM that the PHP is printing expected value for the `$id`?

Comment: It doesn't print when I click the button

Comment: I meant if  you look in your inspector you can see if the PHP actually printed the id there. You may be running the script before it is available too so good idea to wrap it in a document ready statement. https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: When you state (from original) "*file that were fetch*" - do you mean you load your page, then run some javascript that uses `fetch()` to get the php content *after* your page has loaded?

Comment: Try changing `$("#heys").click(function(){...` to `$(document).on("click", "#heys", function() {...` - does that fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your script run before rendering `HTML` of `PHP` file

Could you try to wrap the Javascript code with document ready ?

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#heys").click(function(){
    var fruitCount = $(this).attr('data-fruit');
    console.log(fruitCount);
  });
});
```

Comment: I already wrap it with document ready

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: when I try button click in my main php file it worked but getting id from other php file won't work

Comment: then post the code of your "other PHP file" **in your question** please